# Android: Using AlertDialog in a ListView's onItemClick Event

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an Android app using ListActivity.  When an item in the list is clicked, I'd like to display a confirmation dialog to the user, then perform some action on the clicked item.

However, from the dialog's onClick handler, I can't access the position variable from the list onClick event so I can't tell which item the user clicked.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    // This doesn't work, can't access position from here 
                    Object o = MyListActivity.this.getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                    testFunction(o);
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyListActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to do this?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

    }
});
```

I suppose I could pass the information in by storing it in a member variable on the Activity, but it seems like there should be a better solution!  Can anyone fill me in on the correct/sensible way to do this?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the "correct" way to do this or not but you could do this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
     final int InternalPosition = position;
```

And then in your handler use 'InternalPosition'

```
Object o = MyListActivity.this.getListView().getItemAtPosition(InternalPosition);
```

Not sure if this will work in your case but I know you can access 'final' variables from the listener.